# virtualbox "could not read from the boot medium" with rawdisk

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox

I currently have 2 NVMe ssd in my computer, one with windows installed and the other with ubuntu installed (so a dual boot)

I want to use virtualbox to boot into ubuntu, and I did the following

- create the vmdk file with

  VBoxManage.exe internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ubuntu17.10_link -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1

  [PhysicalDrive1 is indeed the ssd ubuntu is on (the 1TB one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adqut.png)
- create a vm and attach the created vmdk to its NVMe controller

  [a screenshot for the storage config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXDXp.png)
- then when I proceed the boot, I got the error specified in the title

I thought maybe it has something to do with windows permission so I ran virtualbox as admin, still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I first need to unmount the disk in windows (by offlining the disk using diskmgmt.msc or diskpart), then in the virtualbox storage settings there is a "Solid State Drive" for the disk, check that and it can read the disk.